# Point geometry intersects line geometry not working in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, intersection

I have two geometries, one is Line Other one is Point.

I tried find intersects between features

```
QgsGeometry(point).intersects(QgsGeometry(line))
```

I have two cases:

case1: **if point placed on line vertices**

In this case its return True

case2:  **if point placed on line edge (no vertex under point)**

Iin this case its return False

[image: point line]

I tried  `intersects,touches,within,contains,overlaps` all these are returning False.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure they are on top? `line1.distance(point1)`

Comment: i checked distance its give ```1.1``` but physically its intersected

Comment: Point on line is sometimes *impossible* to detect in binary computers, because the point of intersection can't be represented as an IEEE Floating-point value. This is the same basic issue of why you should never do exact real value comparison. You *always* want to test distance less than a threshold.

Answer (score 4):

A point has no 2D area or "range" so if there is a distance between it and another geometry, they are disjunct. A point has to lie exactly on the line for any of the geometry predicates you mention to evaluate to True.

As you mention in your comment, there is a distance of >0 between your point and the line so they do not intersect.

The image you posted is a graphical representation where the line and point are both shown with some width so we can see them. In the geometric model the line actually has a width of zero and the point an area of zero.